# bindingResult.getAllErrors() vs bindingResult.getFieldErrors()

Tags: json, jsp, jquery, spring-mvc

I am developing a application using Spring MVC 3.0 frame work, I have following requirement,

There are multiple form in one jsp page. I am using ajax to submit each form. But after submitting, each form will go to different controller. In controller I will validate input data if there is any error I need to send validation result back to jsp page. Right now I am storing errors into a separate list and sending back to jsp through json response. I am not sure whether to use `bindingResult.getAllErrors()` or `bindingResult.getFieldErrors()` to get list of errors in my controller. What's the difference between both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**getAllErrors()**

> By using bindingResult.getAllErrors you will get all errors, both
>   global and field ones.

**getFieldErrors()**

> By using bindingResult.getFieldErrors() you will get all errors associated with the given field.

Here is a useful [Link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/validation/BindException.html) that may help you understand difference between each better.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

getAllErrors() returns all errors, both Global and Field.  getFieldErrors() only returns errors related to binding field values.  I am not sure what a "Global" error is generated from, as I have never seen one.